# Accessing Excel cells in C# in SSIS

Tags: c#, excel, ssis

I am trying to access excel cell in SSIS `script` code.

I have looked and googled and tried but stopped at this `error`.

I managed to get the excel sheets but could not get a single sheet to read its cells :

```
public void Main()
{
    // TODO: Add your code here
    string path = Dts.Variables["User::SourceFile"].Value.ToString();

    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
    Workbook wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(path);
    //Worksheet excelSheet = wb.ActiveSheet;
    Sheets Shts = excel.Worksheets;

    // ERROR HERE
    Worksheet sh = (Worksheet) Shts.get_Item("Sheet2");

    //Read the first cell
    string test = excelSheet.Cells[1, 1].Value.ToString();

    wb.Close();

    MessageBox.Show(test);

    Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
}
```

Why this line is giving me an `error` :

```
Worksheet sh = (Worksheet) Shts.get_Item("Sheet2");
```

Whats the right way to get the cell data?

Comment: There is some catch with get_Item, trying to remember, will google

Comment: Let me know if I have closed in error, happy to reopen.

Comment: The solution provided in the duplicate question is not working as well.. i tried Shts["Sheet2"]  but still getting error.. anyone with solution please?

Comment: @JeremyThompson please reopen

Comment: Did my answer work mate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code:

```
Workbook wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(path);
Sheets Shts = excel.Worksheets;

// ERROR HERE
Worksheet sh = (Worksheet) Shts.get_Item("Sheet2");
```

I think it should be:

```
Workbook wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(path);
Sheets Shts = wb.Worksheets;  //The WorkBook contains Sheets, not the parent object Excel
var sheet = Shts[1] as Excel.Worksheet;
```

Comment: Nope, still not working.. the SSIS does not give clear error

Comment: Can you debug it in Visual Studio without SSIS just to test?